# Duplicate Template Tab on Sheet with the names based on a range from another Tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a code to create tabs based with the names from another tab range ('Generale').
The tabs generated, naturally are empty.
How to take a template from another tab called "Test"? 
**The Script**

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()}

function createTabs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    ss.getSheetByName('Generale').getRange('G2:G').getValues().filter(String)
        .forEach(function (sn) {
            if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
                ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length);}})}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "take a template"? Does that mean you just want to duplicate the tabs that are listed in `Generale!G2:G`? If so, have you considered the [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) method?

Comment: The script create empty tabs based on the range "G2:G", and so if there are 5 rows, the script create 5 tabs, but empty. How generate these 5 tabs based on the content from a Test tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `options` parameter available in the [`insertSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex,-options) method which allows you to specify a template spreadsheet.

```
function createTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  ss.getSheetByName('Generale').getRange('G2:G').getValues().filter(String)
  .forEach(function (sn) {
    if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
      ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It works fine. After the process the script can also delete the template sheet?

Comment: @Dito You can use the [`deleteSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet) method. Before terminating the function, run `ss.deleteSheet(templateSheet)`.